# External Provider Login .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I had follow this tutorial for setup External Login https://code-maze.com/external-identity-provider-aspnet-core-identity/, after when I want to test login with google account, I write my email, my password. I get to fuunction ExternalLoginConfirmation where ModelState is not valid, always because Principal is null and if I do not specify returnUrl also because of that.
Here are pictures of Debug:
[image: ExternalLogin Method]

[image: ExternalLoginCallback]

Now I'm not sure why returnUrl must be mandatory field, this can easy manage if null is to have to return to Home/Index.
[image]

Then when I submit I got ModelStata.IsValid as false
[image: ExternalLoginConfirmation]

From Program.cs I have this configuration:

```
builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(containerBuilder =>
{
    containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new DefaultDomainModule());
    containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new DefaultInfrastructureModule(false));
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        IConfigurationSection googleAuthSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
        options.ClientId = googleAuthSection["ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = googleAuthSection["ClientSecret"];
        options.SaveTokens = true;

    });
```

And Code from InfrastructureLayer:

```
public static void AddIdentityDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) =>
    services.AddDbContext<IdentityAppDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        })
        .AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityAppDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: You did not specify the return url in your `AddGoogle` method, did you? It must match the one configured in the Google client registration AFAIK.

Comment: As I had follow instructions and had read in Microsoft Docs, I do not need it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0
https://github.com/CodeMazeBlog/identity-aspnetcore/blob/external-provider-identity/IdentityByExamples/IdentityByExamples/Startup.cs

Comment: They are stating that you have to do nothing if you are using the default callback. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0#change-the-default-callback-uri section

Comment: But I didn't change anything, as default on Google client registration is like default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExternalLoginCallBack` returnUrl parameter set to nullable to solves this issue:

from

```
public async Task ExternalLoginCallBack(string returnUrl = null)
```

to

```
public async Task ExternalLoginCallBack(string? returnUrl = null)
```

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22656#issuecomment-640650945